# when installing windows its cut 100 MB for system reserved from my other drive ext4 file system .may be hard disk dameged

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have

1-One SSD 128 s596 turbo on /dev/sda 40G ubuntu and remaining for windows to play game

2-One 2TB on /dev/sdb

3-One 2TB on /dev/sdc

4-One 3TB on /dev/sdd

imaging what happend to me :

windows cut the first 100 MB of my second Drive and i .........:(

just ask do you want to create a system reserved partition ,

where do you?why do you ?how do you? nothing , just cut from another hdd i think

because of the file-system format ext4 and it recognized as a raw partition.

Now my hard drive wont mount or had any partition table i tried to create a new partition table but it was unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

Windows installs it boot partition and boot loader to the MBR of the drive set to boot from with BIOS. It needs a primary NTFS Partition with the boot flag.

If installing and you do not want separate boot partition set boot flag on the primary NTFS partition you install into. Make sure BIOS is set to boot from that drive. Windows primarily has separate Boot partition, so you can encrypt the main install. The boot partition also has the recovery files, so you may need to make the separate repairCD or flash drive to repair Windows easily.

You may be able to use testdisk to restore partition table, but the sectors Windows overwrote will be damaged. 
If you had data you do not have backups, then the only recourse is photorec which is part of testdisk. But that can be a long slow process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,is there anyway to recreate or recover that 100 MB.?